# Ruby not recognizing Grackle object/plugin (Twitter API wrapper) -- "NameError: uninitialized constant Grackle"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

The very first line of this program is where the error happens,

```
require 'grackle'
```

This is code I wrote this morning while I was in class and with the entire program (which starts with 'require grackle') I was able to read tweets and write them directly from the command line. Now I get home and try to run the exact same program on my mac (from irb) and get this:

```
source "grackle.rb"

>> require 'grackle'
NameError: uninitialized constant Grackle
 from ./grackle.rb:5
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from grackle.rb:2
>> require 'json'
=> false
>> require 'highline/import'
=> false
>> 
?>  $client = Grackle::Client.new( :auth => {
...(Oauth keys)...
NameError: uninitialized constant Grackle
from grackle.rb:6
etc etc, every time Grackle gets called a similar error occurs
```

after it tries to run the first line. This initial error then triggers a cascade of errors.

I have installed the grackle gem. What's going on here?

Comment: Rename your file `grackle.rb` to something else like `foo.rb`, then try again. Too many `grackle` files here. Let's start by making sure you are not getting confused about what ruby is loading when you `require 'grackle'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running ruby 1.8. You need to `require 'rubygems'` before you can `require 'grackle'` (the gem).

You are confusing yourself because you have a file named `grackle.rb` in your current directory, but you did not initialize `rubygems` in your `irb` first, so `require 'grackle'` will load the local `grackle.rb` instead of the gem.